# Outlining>Collapse to Definitions no long works for #region . . . #endregion blocks in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2017 RTM, `Collapse to Definitions` command no longer works with #region - #endregion blocks. What's even worse is that even after you scroll through the document to hunt down all the regions and collapse them manually the next time you use the command it actually expands all the regions all over again.

Anyone aware of some way to get `Collapse to Definitions` `Ctrl+M, O` work with #region #endregion blocks in Visual Studio 2017 RTM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Tools\Options\Text Editor\C#\Advanced, there is an option to enable collapsing regions as part of definitions.

Comment: Upvoted because it led me to the answer I needed... I use Collapse All, and VS2017 now includes blocks like if statements and for loops (which I definitely do not want)... fortunately you can turn that off in Tools\Options\Text Editor\C#\Advanced as well - the option is called "Show outlining for code level constructs"

Comment: How about for Javascript? 2012 collapsed '//#region'  blocks when "Collapsing to Defintions" but it appears to have been disabled like C# but I don't see an option to enable it.